# How to split automated tests to different containers

Tags: java, docker, cucumber

I'm used to launch Cucumber automated test against  my own localhost, or a server containing my webapp, with @CucumberOptions, using parameter "tags=" where I put my tag to launch the tests related to it.

But as Cucumber Feature test amount is growing exponentially, I'm facing performance issues which makes some test fail.

As a possible solution, I dockerized my webapp with its dependencies and I launched 3 instances, hoping I'll be able to launch all my test simultaneously, but split into 3 groups, lets say if total amount is 75 features, 25 to each, for example

Since I'm quite newbie on this, which will be the smartest or most common way to do this?

Just looking for some advices of people who is experienced in this field.

Comment: Have you considered running them in parallel? This is supported in Cucumber-jvm as of v4. For more information, see the [docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/)